# how do you do regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

`data='WebSpherePMI_jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage`'

I need to get rid of everything until the first instance of the underline (inclusive) in regex.

I've tried this:

```
re.sub("(^.*\_),"", data)
```

but this get rids of everything before all underlines

```
ProcessCpuUsage
```

I need it to be:

```
jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsag
```

Comment: You really don't even need to use regex for this.

Comment: Definitely don't use regex. It's much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `re.sub("(^.*\_),"", data)`

This makes . match every character in the line. Once it gets to the end, and can't match any more ".", it goes to the next token. Oops, that's a underscore! So, it backtracks back before the _ProcessCpuUsage, where it can match a underscore at the start, and then complete the match.

You should ask the . multiplier to be less greedy.  You also do not need to capture the contents. Drop the parens.  The backslash does nothing. Drop it. The leading line-start anchor also does nothing. Drop it.

> `re.sub(".*?_,", data)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
from string import find

data='WebSpherePMI_jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
result = data[find(data, "_")+1:]
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
result = re.sub("^.*?_", "", text)
```

---

What the regex `^.*?_` does:

- `^`   .. Assert that the position is at the beginning of the string.
- `.*?` .. `Match every character that is not a linebreak character
  between zero and unlimitted times as few times as possible.`
- `-` .. Match the character _

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.index`:

```
>>> data = 'WebSpherePMI_jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
>>> data[data.index('_')+1:]
'jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
```

Using `str.split`

```
>>> data.split('_',1)[1]
'jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
```

Using `str.find`:

```
>>> data[data.find('_')+1:]
'jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
```

Take a look at string methods [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have become a victim of greedy matching. The expression matches the longest sequence that it possibly can.

I know there's a way to turn off greedy matching, but I never remember it. Instead there's a trick I use when there's a character I want to stop at. Instead of matching on every character with `.` I match on every character except the one I want to stop at.

```
re.sub("(^[^_]*\_", "", data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `split()`:

```
s = 'WebSpherePMI_jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage'
print(s.split('_',1)[1])
```

**Result**:

```
jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
import re
def get_last_part(d):
    m = re.match('[^_]*_(.*)', d)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return None

print get_last_part('WebSpherePMI_jvmRuntimeModule_ProcessCpuUsage')
```